# Spark array input not recognized by pandas udf without df.cache?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The output of pack_ts is an array, but if not cache, remove_outlier will raise a codegen error.
My spark version is 2.4.7, and pyarrow version is 12.0.1

```
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(IntegerType()), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def pack_ts(date: pd.Series, pv: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    df = pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "pv": pv})
    df = df.sort_values(by="date")
    df['pv'] = df['pv'].fillna(0)
    return df["pv"]


@pandas_udf(BooleanType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def check_outlier(his_series: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    def func(his):
        pv = pd.Series(his)
        pre = pv.shift(1)
        cond = (pv < 0.1 * pre) & (pre > 1000)
        return cond.any()

    return his_series.apply(func)


def remove_outlier(ky_his):
    ky_his = ky_his.withColumn("outlier", check_outlier(ky_his.his))
    ky_his.cache() # NOTE keep this
    ky_his = ky_his.filter(~ky_his.outlier).drop("outlier")
    return ky_his


# pv: array<int>
schema = StructType([
    StructField("ky", StringType(), True),
    StructField("dt", StringType(), True),
    StructField("pv", IntegerType(), True)
])

# Create some data
data = [
    ("a", "2020-01-01", 1),
    ("a", "2020-01-02", 20000),
    ("a", "2020-01-03", 3),
]

# Create DataFrame
df = spk.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = df.groupby("ky").agg(pack_ts(col("dt").cast(TimestampType()), df.pv).alias("his"))

df.show()

spk.udf.register("check_outlier", check_outlier)

df = remove_outlier(df)

df.show()
```

both remove_outlier and pack_ts work separately.
But pack_ts not work with remove_outlier together without this cache line.